# AMQP v.1.0 Exchange Definition missing

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I was reading RabbitMQ specification on the AMQP 0-9-1 implementation and followed along the examples from the tutorial page which were helpful on explaining Exchanges and Queues. 
The new latest and major release of the AMQP spec v. 1.0 has been out for two months and according to this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol#Specification_revisions_and_the_future_of_AMQP) article the definition of Exchange/fanout/direct/topic bindings have been removed. Here is the full spec for [AMQP v1.0](http://www.amqp.org/confluence/download/attachments/720900/amqp.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1318011006000).

I've been reading the full v1.0 spec but it's very technical and has no general explanation of how it can be used in a scenario for example a Producer and consumer application or how it's different from 0-10 and how to correlate the old Binding and Exchange notion to the new one.

How does all this Exchange functionality fit in the new protocol. If there are example usages with code example of some lib implementation that would be helpful.

Comment: Side note: the early access edition of [RabbitMQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/videla/) is well worth reading if you want to get up to speed on RabbitMQ quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AMQP 1.0 in its current state does not specify broker behavior (i.e. how brokers handle and distribute messaages), only how to 2 nodes in AMQP network communicate between them self. There is draft document named "Broker behavior" that is intended to specify this area, but it is in very early stage since most of the 1.0 activity up to now has been concentrated around core protocol specification. So you could say that in some regards, 1.0 specifies much less than old 0.x versions

So until "Broker behavior" part of the spec reaches at least some maturity, it would be hard to come up with 1.0 example that would be equivalent to publishing to exchange and subscribing to it, since different amqp 1.0 entities could implement it quite differently. Probably, many amqp vendors will implement similar behavior to their 0.9 products. For instance RabbitMQ experimental 1.0 implementation provides 1.0 access to their existing 0.9 broker. But that is just my guessing. [Here are my some other thoughts about current state of  AMQP 1.0](http://www.cloud208.com/blogica/A+bird+eye+view+on+AMQP+1.0)

Comment: I was wondering why the spec didn't have these specification.  btw, I thought RabbitMQ latest one is 0-10 ( I realized that 1.0 is not the same as 1.0). So nodes would essentially send msgs to each other and each device that wants to send messages would have to be a node itself?

Comment: yes 0.10 is (not very popular) iteration of 0.9x protocol version, while 1.0 is completely different beast.

Comment: I also think that 1.0 will need to describe behavior of brokers in order to become more widely accepted, and substitute 0.9x family. As far I have been told, AMQP group wanted to concentrate on core of the protocol first, and work on behavior later. Anyway, we have to see if work on broker behavior will start to heat up now that the core of the protocol is done.

Comment: I've been reading the 0-10 spec and implementations of Qpid and MRG (red hat) it seems good and complete. but you don't agree with this?

Comment: I have no direct experience with 0.10, my comment (that it is not very popular) was based on RabbitMQ which is my kind of lacmus test, is not implementing it.

Comment: I see. Well thank you very much your time to put in comments, they have been most certainly helpful.